# Run connectedAndroidTest and skip uninstall

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, automated-tests

Is there a way to call the task connectedAndroidTest and skip the uninstall task at the end of the process ?

At the end of the test execution, the app is uninstalled from the device, but I would like to keep the app on the device.

from http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Running-tests :

> As mentioned previously, checks requiring a connected device are launched with the anchor task called connectedCheck. This depends on the task connectedDebugAndroidTest and therefore will run it. This task does the following:
>
> - Ensure the app and the test app are built (depending on assembleDebug and assembleDebugAndroidTest).
> - Install both apps.
> - Run the tests.
> - Uninstall both apps.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question a bit so that it is easily understood??

Comment: added some explanation, but I don't see what was unclear. Which info do you need ?

Comment: "...The app is uninstalled from the device, but I would like to keep the app on the device."?

Comment: @Mandy8055 "at the end of _TEST EXECUTION", so it makes sense.

Comment: @ThomasV see perhaps https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing-templates/tree/master/AndroidTestingBlueprint ? i haven't got time right now to dig into, try and see if it can make a viable answer

Comment: couldn't find anything. A solution would be to run the android test with a CLI, but I won't get the results in a report.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looking at the sorce of gradle plugin there is no way to prevent uninstalling app at the end of test task. You can check that in `SimpleTestCallable` class of android gradle plugin.

From what i see there are two options to acchive what you want.

First one is to reinstall app after your connected check is done. Command to do that would look something like this. `./gradlew connectedCheck installDebug installDebugAndroidTest` This will execute test on device and delete apps from it. But after that it will reinstall app and test app. So app will still be removed and then installed which means a bit of owerhead but at least apps will not be recompiled twice since you are executing in same gradle execution.

Second option is to not use gradle for executing tests but use adb instead. 
To do this you first need to install app and test app through gradle.
`./gradlew installDebug installDebugAndroidTest`

After that you can execute tests through adb. by caling `adb shell am instrument -w com.example.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner`.

When this is done you can run your cli tests since both app and test app are still installed.

With second approach you would lose all the benefits of executing test wit gradle. Such as code coverage and executing in multiple proceses, etc.

Comment: The drawback of the first approach is that it results in removing data (shared preferences, sqlite db) as long as apk is completely removed and installed from scratch.

Comment: For that you could use https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.AdbOptions.html. And add `-k` option that preserves data when app is removed.

Comment: Only thing is tat it won't work with `ShardedTestRunner` but only with `SimpleTestRunner`

Comment: Still, that is applicable to second approach, **not** first, because you do not have control on flags that `connectedCheck` does internally. In other words, you cannot change `./gradlew ...` command in a way, that data is not removed after UI tests, correct?

Comment: No it is applicable to first approach and you can define flags in `build.gradle` file by adding `android { adbOptions { installOptions "-r" } }`

Comment: Isn't that `installOptions`? There is **no** `uninstallOptions`. Had there been `uninstallOptions`, then `-k` could be passed, which would resolve my concern. Do you impose, that `installOptions` also affect on `uninstallOptions`?

Comment: That is exactly it. Install options are also passed as uninstall parrameters.  At leas that is what I see in source.

Comment: When i try to add option -k to install options like this:
adbOptions { installOptions "-k" } i have exception that '-k' is not supported. Which version of gradle do you use?